# Attachment of Taxonomy Term Description shows All descriptions on term page instead of only one

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a View page to display a sortable table of Category | Model | Brand | Price. Each product has it's own content types that has all of these fields entered. Category is a List, Model is the title field, Brand is a term reference, and price is an integer field.

I created a page view from the data of of this Product Content type and used contextual filters to display different views of tables at the /category and the /brand level. Because I had some trouble getting two contextual filters to work on the same Page view, I created a new page view [Brand] for the contextual filter for the Brands taxonomy terms. (see question and comments here: Can you display data dynamically from a textfield in the URL and Name of Views?)

Now I created an Attachment to attach to the Brand view. I created the attachment because I would like the Term Description to be above the Brand view that displays the Product Category / Model / Price for each Brand generated by the view. The trouble is that I am getting the description of every brand printed instead of just the brand currently being displayed on the page. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? I feel like I need a specific filter for this to work.. I've tried different configurations that produce the same result.

Below are my screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gTcI.png --> The attachment

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S20sQ.png --> The page view for the taxonomy term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a contextual filter to the attachment view. This should be the taxonomy ID. And you have to set the **Inherit contextual filters:** to **Yes**

Comment: Do you mean Content: Has taxonomy term ID, or Taxonomy term: Term ID?

Comment: Aha! Content: Has taxonomy term ID worked!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!